# passing files from R to Java

Tags: java, jsp, r

I m passing multiple tab delim files into R via Java.The R programm merges those tab delim files as single file and sends back to java and it is captured in the variable "name".Now I want to rename and save that file stored in "name" as tab delim using save dialog box in windows.Any help highly appreciated.Here is the java code:

```
import org.rosuda.REngine.*;

public class rjava {
    // Before this run Rserve() command in R


    public String ana(String filenames)
    {
        String name = "";
            try{

                System.out.println("INFO: Trying to connect to R ");
                RConnection c = new RConnection();
                System.out.println("INFO: Connected to R");
                System.out.println("INFO: The Server version is "+ c.getServerVersion());
            //  c.voidEval("source('D:/combine/combining_files.r')");
                c.voidEval("source('D:/combine/merge.r')");
                c.assign("file",filenames);
            //  name = (c.eval("fn(file)").asString());
                name = (c.eval("combine (file)").asString());
                c.close();
                }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
            System.out.println("ERROR: In Connection to R");
            System.out.println("The Exception is "+ e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: how, *exactly* are you calling R from Java?

Comment: I used rosuda REngine to call R.

Comment: It's unclear what is being asked here. What is the one thing which you cannot figure out? How have you tried to solve that one thing? Can you share example code?

Comment: @JD Long I ve edited my question as precise as I can and also given you the code.

Comment: Your question is much clearer! Good edit.

Comment: @JD Long Any idea of how to make it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find passing complex objects between R and Java to be a pain the ass. I would not pass the full data, but rather would pass only file names as a string. Either have Java tell R to write out the new file (my pref) or have Java read in the file and then write out with a new name.

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the R program, so that it outputs files in the same path with a given file name, such as `[path]/filename.out`?

Otherwise, you can modify the execte string so that the R program outputs in a given location.
See http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line

> When working at a command line on UNIX or Windows, the command ‘R’ can be used both for starting the main R program in the form `R [options] [<infile] [>outfile]`

-- EDIT
I just saw that you are using an RConnection. According to the R docs, you can define where to pipe stdout

> The function sink, `sink("record.lis")` will divert all subsequent output from the console to an external file, record.lis.

Comment: currently  my program can select the text files from the folder(this part in java and JSP and Servlets) and sends the selected files to the R which then performs R's calculation and writes in the folder with name what I ve specified in "write.table" function.But I want the name of the file should be written by user not by default name.

Comment: I'm just familiar with command-line invocation of R. Are you using something else?

Comment: actually My program returns the merged file into java.and in the java code i need to save it with my own name using standard Save dialog box on Windows.